# Returning ActionResult.UserExit seems to have no effect

Tags: wix, custom-action

I have a custom action that returns ActionResult.UserExit which as far as I can tell should stop the installation from proceeding. This doesn't however seem to be the case. The install continues as if the custom action was successful.

The custom action, CheckMILInstallation is defined as:

```wix
<CustomAction Id="CheckMILInstallation" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="CheckMILInstallation"></CustomAction>
```

and is triggered from a dialog button:

```wix
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="DALicenseDlg">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Event="DoAction"  Value="CheckMILInstallation" order="1">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Property="NextDialog"                 Value="VerifyReadyDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Property="VerifyReadyDlg_Back"        Value="DASetupTypeDlg" Order="2">1</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Property="NextDialog"                 Value="DAInstallCSWDlg" Order="3">INSTALLIDE="1" AND VS2010_VCSHARP_FOLDER</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Property="DAInstallCSWDlg_Back"       Value="DASetupTypeDlg"  Order="3">INSTALLIDE="1" AND VS2010_VCSHARP_FOLDER</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Property="NextDialog"                 Value="DAStartWebsiteDlg" Order="4">INSTALLRT="1" AND CONFLICTING_WEBSITE</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Property="DAStartWebsiteDlg_Back"     Value="DASetupTypeDlg"    Order="4">INSTALLRT="1" AND CONFLICTING_WEBSITE</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Property="NextDialog"                 Value="DAMultiInstallDirDlg" Order="5">InstallPathEditable OR ExamplesPathEditable</Publish>
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Property="DAMultiInstallDirDlg_Back"  Value="DASetupTypeDlg"       Order="5">InstallPathEditable OR ExamplesPathEditable</Publish>      
<Publish Dialog="DASetupTypeDlg"       Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="[NextDialog]" Order="6">1</Publish>
```

The MSI log does indicate the right return value, but then proceeds to create the next dialog as if it was successful:

```
MSI (c) (78:EC) [11:05:56:926]: Doing action: CheckMILInstallation
Action 11:05:56: CheckMILInstallation. 
Action start 11:05:56: CheckMILInstallation.
MSI (c) (78:CC) [11:05:56:926]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\MSI6F00.tmp, Entrypoint: CheckMILInstallation
Action ended 11:06:00: CheckMILInstallation. Return value 2.
MSI (c) (78:EC) [11:06:00:582]: Note: 1: 2727 2:  
MSI (c) (78:EC) [11:06:00:582]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding NextDialog property. Its value is 'VerifyReadyDlg'.
MSI (c) (78:EC) [11:06:00:582]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding VerifyReadyDlg_Back property. Its value is 'DASetupTypeDlg'.
MSI (c) (78:EC) [11:06:00:582]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying NextDialog property. Its current value is 'VerifyReadyDlg'. Its new value: 'DAInstallCSWDlg'.
MSI (c) (78:EC) [11:06:00:582]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DAInstallCSWDlg_Back property. Its value is 'DASetupTypeDlg'.
MSI (c) (78:EC) [11:06:00:582]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Modifying NextDialog property. Its current value is 'DAInstallCSWDlg'. Its new value: 'DAMultiInstallDirDlg'.
MSI (c) (78:EC) [11:06:00:582]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding DAMultiInstallDirDlg_Back property. Its value is 'DASetupTypeDlg'.
Action 11:06:00: DAMultiInstallDirDlg. Dialog created
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your ActionResult.UserExit is defined, but the docs seem to indicate that the value should be 1602, not 2 for a user exit. The value 2 seems reserved for the results of script custom actions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368072(v=vs.85).aspx

Script CA return values:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371254(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ActionResult is an enumeration used when returning values from managed custom actions. ActionResult.UserExit is indeed defined as 1602. It simply appears as 2 in the logs as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: My guess is that you need to arrange for an EndDialog action with Exit. I'm not sure that custom actions that return exit behave the same in the UI (as opposed to direct call from a sequence).